# Firebase Functions Error : DeprecationWarning: grpc.load - when the website is running

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, grpc, angular-universal

**Issue**: Firebase Functions keeps giving me an error called: DeprecationWarning: grpc.load when the website is running.

I have no idea what this is for? or how to get rid of it.
Could it be something to do with firebase functions and server side rendering.

**Exact Log Error**:

> DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with
> grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead

**Tech**:

Angular 7, Angular Universal (SSR), Firebase, Firebase Functions.

**My functions package json:**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.13.6",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.11",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.3.14",
    "@hackages/ngxerrors": "^6.0.3",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.13.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "0.0.0",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-pwa/offline": "^6.1.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^4.4.2",
    "angular-google-map": "0.0.2",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "basscss": "7.1.1",
    "basscss-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^5.9.3",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "geofirestore": "^3.2.3",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "latlon-geohash": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "lozad": "^1.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.17",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-prevent-double-submission": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "sass-lint": "^1.12.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**My functions/index.js file**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const { app } = require('./dist/server');

exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Error screen shot:**

[image]

Comment: [Are there any port warnings ?, this might be helpful](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/issues/301)

Comment: @SouravDutta that link says its something called: gax-nodejs but I dont have any dependencies in my package called that name

Comment: It also talks about port? is this the port number in the functions package.json? if so how I change the port number because it must be using the default one

Comment: somethings like `firebase serve --only functions --port=9000` not sure though

Comment: @SouravDutta it seems to have fixed it so far - I will keep monitoring the logs to see if it appears again

Comment: @SouravDutta I've just got the error again. Not sure if its port related. my ports 9000

Comment: [is the timeout still occurring ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665686/firebase-functions-log-error-function-execution-attempt-timed-out-function-inv) @AngularM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191785/discussion-between-sourav-dutta-and-angularm).

Answer (score 1):

> [**Issue Closed
>   here**](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/issues/301#issuecomment-425420695)

Chances are, there will be other *Warnings as the port in use*

Running `firebase serve --only functions --port=9000` fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. Ive tried this and monitored it, but sadly I still get the same issue. Any other ideas I can try? thanks