# Firebase Functions Log Error: function execution attempt timed out. Function invocation was interrupted

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular7, angular-universal

**Issue:** Error: function execution attempt timed out. Function invocation was interrupted.

**Exact Log Error:**

> Error: function execution attempt timed out. Function invocation was
>   interrupted.

**Tech:**

Angular 7, Angular Universal (SSR), Firebase, Firebase Functions.

**My functions/index.js file**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const { app } = require('./dist/server');

exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Screen shot of the Firebase Functions Log Error:**

[image]

**My functions package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions --port=9000",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions --port=9000",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.13.6",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.11",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.3.14",
    "@hackages/ngxerrors": "^6.0.3",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.13.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "0.0.0",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-pwa/offline": "^6.1.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^4.4.2",
    "angular-google-map": "0.0.2",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "basscss": "7.1.1",
    "basscss-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^5.9.3",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "geofirestore": "^3.2.3",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "latlon-geohash": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "lozad": "^1.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.17",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-prevent-double-submission": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "sass-lint": "^1.12.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: What’s the point of posting this? So, you had a timeout; try again! Chances are this has nothing to do with the application code which you didn’t provide. If this error is occurring repeatedly, then explain that in the post. No one here is going to be able to reproduce this issue with the information provided.

Comment: Hi @R.Richards what information would you like me to provide? I get this error showing up in my firebase functions logs in the firebase console.

Comment: This is what you need to provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Add this to your index.js 

`exports.afterTimeout = (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // May not execute if function's timeout is <2 minutes
    console.log('Function running...');
    res.end();
  }, 120000); // 2 minute delay
};`  [this might be helpful, check the **Timeout** section](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec)

Comment: Thanks @SouravDutta I will add this/try now

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same error but I get timeout every time.